# Connecting 2 linux devices using ethernet

Tags: wifi, ethernet, multiple-machines

I have a laptop (without working WiFi), and a computer connected wirelessly. Both devices are connected by an ethernet cable, and both run Arch Linux. On a previous install (Manjaro), both devices were detected automatically and the laptop could tether through the cable, however I cannot do this after reinstalling with Arch.

I'm running KDE, so I'd either need to use its settings UI, or the command line

```bash
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:c6:91:fe:ed:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:71:96:f6:c5:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.18/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 858089sec preferred_lft 858089sec
    inet6 fe80::2075:e030:c91f:5d44/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Notice `state DOWN` on the link. This needs to be `UP` for the network to function. `ip link set enp1s0 up` is a good first step.

Comment: @WarzauWynn Note that earlier on the same line it says `<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>`. So the network interface has already been configured to *want* to be UP, but it is unable to achieve that. `NO-CARRIER` would indicate a problem with the cable. `ethtool -i enp1s0` and `ethtool enp1s0` might shed more light to the situation: the first command will identify the NIC driver and firmware version (if applicable), the latter should tell us what kind of link the card is trying to establish at this time: is it auto-crossover (MDI-X), is it autonegotiating the speed & duplex, etc.

Comment: `ethtool -i enp1s0`:

driver: r8169

version: 5.18.15-arch1-1

firmware-version: rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13

expansion-rom-version: 

bus-info: 0000:01:00.0

supports-statistics: yes

supports-test: no

supports-eeprom-access: no

supports-register-dump: yes

supports-priv-flags: no

Comment: The MDI-X thing also said it was `MDI-X: Unknown` :/

Answer (score 0):

If there is no switch/hub in between and they are connected directly using a network cable, onsider using [Crossover network cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). Not all drivers detect direct cable connections and do the swapping.

Comment: wow, that's a blast from the past – haven't had to do that since 1998, but you're right, if neither end is gigabit ethernet and neither end supports auto-crossover, that'd be necessary. It's a bit curious it used to work on a different OS, though, as this is usually actually a hardware function.

Comment: Yeah, it worked on the previous linux install, so it shouldn't be a hardware issue